# Can I link .png images I have stored in res/mipap to html files I have stored in android_asset, so WebView shows both text and images in an html file?

Tags: html, android-studio, webview, localhost, android-mipmap

I have an Android app which uses the WebView function, it opens html files inside my app from a local host that have been stored in the android_asset folder when prompted. However, the WebView function only shows the text in the html file, it does not show the images that I have linked into the code of the html document, these are stored in res/mipmap. It is important to me that my app can show both text and images when I use WebView to open the html file. It is also important that the html files and the images are stored in a place that means they will be added to the installable (so that the user does not have to be connected to the internet to use the App or move any files around themselves). Is it possible to link an image stored on a local host in something like android_asset or res/mipmap so that I can see both text and the image when I open the html file in WebView?
The link to the images that does not work is in res/mipmap, it is: img src = "file:///mipmap-hdpi/car.png" alt = "Test Image"

Answer (score 0):

I made a new folder inside android_asset called imagepng. I then put the .png's in this folder (so the link to the image in the htlml file looks like ). The html file now calls the .png image from this place and I can see it on the app. I do not know yet if this makes it into the installable so it can be run locally from the
smart phone..........My original mistake was trying to put the images directly into android_asset as it does not allow this.